# ¿como accedo a los valores en un objeto anidado usando for in?

Tags: bucle-for, objeto

*tengo este objeto con objetos y debo iterar con un bucle for in y devolver cuantos tienn el valor online true*

```
let usuarios = {
    luis:{
        edad:34,
        online: true
        },
   pedro:{
        edad:14,
        online: true
        },
   diego:{
        edad:44,
        online: false
        },
   ana:{
        edad:24,
        online: false
        }
}
```

Comment: Hola, pudiste lograrlo?

Comment: si es justamente lo que necesitaba, aun me cuesta un poco el tema de objetos anidados, gracias por la respuesta¡

Comment: si es objeto tubiera otro objeto tendria que agregar otros corchetes? como si fuera un elemento de un array, es decir un array dentro de otro array?

Comment: Es que por eso fue mi duda en un inicio, pense que te habias confundido con un array de objs. No olvides evaluar alguna de las respuestas!. Abrazos y happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

espero sea lo que preguntas.

```js
let usuarios = {
    luis:{
        edad:34,
        online: true
        },
   pedro:{
        edad:14,
        online: true
        },
   diego:{
        edad:44,
        online: false
        },
   ana:{
        edad:24,
        online: false
        }
}

count = 0;
for(let user in usuarios) {
  if(usuarios[user].online === true) {
     count = count + 1;
  }
}

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues simplemente escribiendo correctamente el bucle. Este código te recorre el objeto completo

```
let usuarios = {
    luis:{
        edad:34,
        online: true
        },
   pedro:{
        edad:14,
        online: true
        },
   diego:{
        edad:44,
        online: false
        },
   ana:{
        edad:24,
        online: false
        }
}
let text = "";
for (let x in usuarios) {
  document.write(x+'<br>')
  for (let i in usuarios[x])
    {
     document.write(i+': '+usuarios[x][i]+'<br>');
    }
    document.write('<br>')
}
```

**for** ( variable **in** objeto) recorre el objeto y asigna a variable el valor del key de cada campo.
Modificarlo al caso que comentas es simple, y lógicamente se simplifica bastante:

```
contar = 0;
for (let x in usuarios) {
  if(usuarios[x].online){
      contar++;
   }
}
document.write(contar);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, me ayudo a entender mejor el problema¡